# Problem to understand Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

In the [Hungerford's book](http://libgen.org/get?nametype=orig&md5=3CF13F219E5121470C6D659A9AB9F46C) and following the answers of this question: 
[Help to understand the ring of polynomials terminology in $n$ indeterminates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396936/help-to-understand-the-ring-of-polynomials-terminology-in-n-indeterminates) I have troubles to understand the following remark in the page 152:

[image]

My question is $\varphi$f is a composition of functions? because if so, it is not well defined because $f\in R[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $s_1,...,s_n\in S$

Thanks a lot

Comment: $\varphi f$ is not a composition of functions.  $\varphi f(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ is a symbol representing the summation $\sum\varphi(a_i)s_1^{k_i1}\ldots s_n^{k_{in}}$.  You can think of $\varphi f$ as the image of $f$ under the induced ring homomorphism $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to S$ which maps $x_i$ to $s_i$ and $a_i\in R$ to $\varphi(a_i)\in S$.

Comment: Note that $f$ is a formal polynomial, not a function. Also, $\phi f$ is defined in the paragraph you cite. Does this help?

Comment: @Jared thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2):

If $\,f\,$ is a polynomial in $\,n\,$ indeterminates with coefficients in $\,R\,$ , we **want** $\,\phi f\,$ to be an element in $\,S\,$ , and that's why there's written $\,\phi f(s_1,...,s_n)\;,\;\;s_i\in S\,$ . For this to happen, we **need**  the coefficients of the polynomial $\,f\,$ in $\,R[x_1,...,x_n]\,$ to be mapped to elements in $\,S\,$ , and this is precisely what $\,\phi(a_i)\,$ accomplishes.

So, in short, $\,\phi f\,$ is definitely not composition of function since, as you remark, this wouldn't make any sense in this case.