# Theorem 4, Section 3.5 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $n$ a positive integer. For each $i= 1,2,…,n$ let $x_i\in R[x_1,…,x_n]$ be defined by $x_i(\epsilon_i)=1_R$ and $x_i(u)=0$ for $u\neq \epsilon_i$.
>
> (i) For each integer $k\in N$, $x_i^k(k\epsilon_i) = 1_R$ and $x_i^k(u) = 0$ for $u\neq k\epsilon_i$;
>
> (ii) for each $(k_1,…,k_n) \in N^n$, $x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2},…,x_n^{k_n}(k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_n\epsilon_n)=1_R$ and
> $x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2},…,x_n^{k_n}(u) = 0$ for $u\neq k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_n\epsilon_n$;
>
> (iii) $x_i^s x_j^t = x_j^t x_i^s$ for all $s,t\in N$ and all $i,j = 1,2, ... ,n$;
>
> (iv) $x_i^t r = r x_i^t$ for all $r\in R$ and all $t\in N$;
>
> (v) for every polynomial $f$ in $R[x_1,…,x^n]$ there exist unique elements $a_{k_1,…,k_n}\in R$, indexed by all $(k_1,…,k_n)\in N^n$ and nonzero for at most a finite number of $(k_1,…,k_n)\in N^n$, such that $$f= \sum a_{k_1,…,k_n} x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n}$$ where the sum is over all $(k_1,…,k_n)\in N^n$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/396959/861687) answer describe why this theorem (notation for polynomial in $n$-indeterminant) is pretty important. Proof with adequate details for this theorem are hard to find on internet, even in books. That’s why I have written proof of this theorem below.

This is not a multiple question in one post. Our goal is to write polynomial in $n$-indeterminant as sum of “elementary” polynomial in $n$-indeterminant. Intermediate steps [(i), (ii), (iii) and (iv)] are essential to achieve our goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof:** **(i)** We claim $\forall k\in N$, $x_i^k(k\epsilon_i)=1_R$ and $x_i^k(u)=0$ for $u\neq k\epsilon_i$. Base case: $k=0$. Then $x_i^0=1_{R[x_1,…,x_n]}$ by definition. Thus $x_i^0(0,…,0)=1_R$ and $x_i^0(u)=0$ for $u\neq (0,…,0)$. For $k=1$, it is precisely the definition of $x_i$. Inductive step: Suppose $x_i^k(k\epsilon_i)=1_R$ and $x_i^k(u)=0$ for $u\neq k\epsilon_i$, for some $k\geq 1$. Then
$$\begin{align} x_i^{k+1}\left((k+1)\epsilon_i\right) &= x_i^k x_i\left((k+1)\epsilon_i\right) \\ &= \sum_{v+w=(k+1)\epsilon_i}x_i^k(v)x_i(w)\\ &=x_i^k(k\epsilon_i)x_i(\epsilon_i)\\ &= 1_R.
\end{align}$$
Third equality follows from inductive hypothesis and definition of $x_i$. Let $u\in N^n$. Then
$$x_i^{k+1}(u) =x_i^kx_i(u)= \sum_{v+w=u}x_i^k(v)x_i(w)$$
Pick an arbitrary term from the summation, $x_i^k(v)x_i(w)$. Note $$x_i^k(v)x_i(w)\neq 0 \implies x_i^k(v)\neq 0 \text{ and }x_i(w)\neq 0 \implies v=k\epsilon_i \text{ and }w=\epsilon_i \implies u=(k+1)\epsilon_i.$$
Therefore if $u\neq (k+1)\epsilon_i$, then $x_i^{k+1}(u) = \sum_{v+w=u}x_i^k(v)x_i(w)=0$. Thus $x_i^{k+1}\left((k+1)\epsilon_i\right)=1_R$ and $x_i^{k+1}(u)=0$ for $u\neq (k+1)\epsilon_i$. By mathematical induction, statement holds for $\forall k\in N$.

**(ii)** Let $(k_1,…,k_n)\in N^n$. We claim $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$, $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_i^{k_i}(k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_i\epsilon_i)=1_R$ and $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_i^{k_i}(u)=0$ for $u\neq k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_i\epsilon_i$. Base case: $i=1$. It is simply (i). Inductive step: Suppose $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_i^{k_i}(k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_i\epsilon_i)=1_R$ and $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_i^{k_i}(u)=0$ for $u\neq k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_i\epsilon_i$, for some $1\leq i\lt n$. Then $$\begin{align} x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_i^{k_i}x_{i+1}^{k_{i+1}}(k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_{i+1} \epsilon_{i+1}) &=  \sum_{v+w= k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_{i+1} \epsilon_{i+1}}(x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_i^{k_i})(v) x_{i+1}^{k_{i+1}}(w) \\ &= (x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_i^{k_i})(k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_i \epsilon_i) x_{i+1}^{k_{i+1}}(k_{i+1} \epsilon_{i+1}) \\ &= 1_R. \end{align}$$
Second equality follows from inductive hypothesis and (i). Proof of $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_{i+1}^{k_{i+1}}(u)=0$ for $u\neq k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_{i+1} \epsilon_{i+1}$ is same (with slight changes) as in the proof of (i). Thus $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_{i+1}^{k_{i+1}}(k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_{i+1}\epsilon_{i+1})=1_R$ and $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_{i+1}^{k_{i+1}}(u)=0$ for $u\neq k_1\epsilon_1 +…+k_{i+1}\epsilon_{i+1}$. By mathematical induction, statement holds for $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$. Put $i=n$, our desired result.

**(iii)** Let $s,t\in N$ and $i,j=1,…,n$. If $u=sk_i+tk_j$, then $x_i^sx_j^t(u)=1_R=x_j^tx_i^s(u)$. If $u \neq sk_i+tk_j$, then $x_i^sx_j^t(u)=0=x_j^tx_i^s(u)$. Thus $x_i^sx_j^t(u)=x_j^tx_i^s(u)$. Details of (iii) is similar to that of (i) or (ii).

**(iv)** let $r\in R$ and $t\in N$. Author didn’t explicitly defined multiplication of polynomial in $n$-indeterminants with an element of ring $R$. “Natural” way to define multiplication is following: $rx_i^t, x_i^tr\in R[x_1,,…,x_n]$ is given by $(rx_i^t)(u)=rx_i^t(u)$ and $(x_i^tr)(u)=x_i^t(u)r$ for all $u\in N^n$, respectively. Since $R\overset{\varphi}{\cong} \text{ subring of }R[x_1,…,x_n]$, $r$ can be identified with its image $f_r$, where $f_r(0,…,0)=r$ and $f_r(u)=0$ if $u\neq (0,…,0)$. Above definition of $rx_i^t$ and $x_i^tr$ is consistent if we replace $r$ with $f_r$, i.e. $(f_rx_i^t)(u)=rx_i^t(u)$ and $(x_i^tf_r)(u)=x_i^t(u)r$ for all $u\in N^n$.

If $u\neq t\epsilon_i$, then $x_i^t(u)=0$ and $(x_i^tr)(u)=0=(r x_i^t)(u)$. If $u= t\epsilon_i$, then $x_i^t(u)=1_R$ and $(x_i^tr)(u)=r=(r x_i^t)(u)$. Thus $x_i^tr=rx_i^t$.

**(v)** Take $a_{k_1,…,k_n}=f(k_1,…,k_n)$. Use (ii) to show $$f(u) = \left( \sum_{(k_1,…,k_n)\in N^n} a_{k_1,…,k_n} x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n} \right)(u)$$
for all $u\in N^n$.

---

Result (iii) and (iv) says that polynomial is independent of how we express them. To be precise, $$a_{k_1,…,k_n} x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n} = x_i^{k_i}\cdots x_j^{k_j} a_{k_1,…,k_n} x_p^{k_p}\cdots x_q^{k_q}$$ where $i,j,p,q=1,…,n$.